# Bash and Awk: write results of sort to a new file line by line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file `myinputfile.txt` that looks like this:

```
2.34 1.25 ./RUN1 ./RUN1/mod/file1.csv
3.34 1.25 ./RUN1 ./RUN1/mod/file2.csv
1.32 1.25 ./RUN2 ./RUN2/mod/file1.csv
4.35 1.25 ./RUN2 ./RUN2/mod/file2.csv
```

I want a new file that contains the line that has the maximum value of column 1 for each value of `RUN*`. Desired contents of new file (`myresultsfile.txt`):

```
3.34 1.25 ./RUN1 ./RUN1/mod/file2.csv
4.35 1.25 ./RUN2 ./RUN2/mod/file2.csv
```

I have a script that mostly gets me there, but doesn't put things on new lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
resultsfile="myresults.txt"
inputfile="myinputfile.txt"
res1=$(sort -k3,3r $inputfile | awk '{split($nF,d,"/")} !a[d[3]]++')
echo $res1 >> $resultsfile
```

Comment: What is the purpose of not quoting your shell variable `$res1`? Are you happy with the result of doing that? Quoting shell variables is something you must do by default and only decide NOT to do when you have a specific purpose in mind and fully understand the consequences (hint - you are experiencing some right now). ITYM `$NF` or `$0` in your awk script, not `$nF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `sort` assisted `awk`

```
$ sort -k1nr file | awk '!a[$3]++'

3.34 1.25 ./RUN1 ./RUN1/mod/file2.csv
4.35 1.25 ./RUN2 ./RUN2/mod/file2.csv
```

simply redirect to a new file

```
$ sort -k1nr file | awk '!a[$3]++' > sorted_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '$1 > max[$3] { max[$3] = $1; rec[$3] = $0 } END { for (i in rec) print rec[i] }' file

3.34 1.25 ./RUN1 ./RUN1/mod/file2.csv
4.35 1.25 ./RUN2 ./RUN2/mod/file2.csv
```

- `max` is an associative array that holds max value of first column by the key as column 3
- `rec` is an associative array that holds full line by the key as column 3